# Ping IP address timed out while vagrant up is running

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, ip-address, ping

I'm new to laravel and I'm learning to work with vagrant. 
When I do vagrant up I get no errors but still the IP address is not working or the ping shows 'request timed out'.

(I have the latest versions of PHP and Virtualbox, and my virtualization in the BIOS menu is enabled)

Can you help me?

Here is my Homestead.yaml file :

```
ip: 192.168.10.192
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: 'C:\Users\ProjectName'
        to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
    -
        map: homestead.app
        to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
databases:
    - homestead
name: ProjectName
hostname: ProjectName
```

Comment: What ip address are you pinging?

Comment: 192.168.10.192 - I used this ip in my Homestead.yaml file

Comment: When you do vagrant ssh...what happens?

Comment: I get no error. It just logs in

Comment: Can you show the yaml file to us please?

Comment: Okay, I added the file to my question

Comment: Have you tried comparing it to the original yaml from the GitHub?
I see you have some newlines in places where there shouldn't be any.
https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/resources/Homestead.yaml
And have you tried adding a host entry to your hosts file on your pc? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#configuring-homestead Under the header: The Hosts File. and tried the domain name?
By the way, next time copy and paste the yaml in your post, please do not screenshot and link to it! (Advantages are you can edit the code!) You also did not really anonimize it which you should.

Comment: The yaml file was automatically generated like this, if I change it to the original yaml from the Github, the result stays te same (Request times out).

Comment: I added the ip address and homestead.app to the hosts file, but als this chances nothing because I cannot reach the ip address (or homestead.app) if I try to ping it

Answer (score 0):

Did you already find a solution? check http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: I also see `folders:
    -
        map: 'C:\Users\ProjectName'
        to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
    -
        map: homestead.app
        to: /home/vagrant/Code/public` is that correct? I created a tutorial here that I think you might find useful: [link](http://garcia-fraile.com/index.php/2017/09/12/vagrant-virtual-box-windows-homestead/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The Vagrantfile was wrongly created. I created the app with the composer but I should've used 'laravel new project'. Thank you all for your help!